# Best way to setup Vue route guards that can't be manually changed in developer console

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can easily allow access to my routes by setting my variable to `true` in developer tools with:

`document.querySelector('#app').__vue__.$store.commit("setAuthenticated", true)`

How can I make it so that I can't do this and get past my route guard for accessing a route that should only be for authenticated users?

Comment: Have you had a look at the vue-router documentation? Either the [route meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) and/or the [advanced navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation) might help you to solve your question. Or how do you do your routing?

Comment: I think the only way to ensure it is if the proper controls are implemented on the backend. So even if the users tampers with the JS code your backend that presumably provide your data will enforce authorization.